# removing a unique div tag when clicked close button

Tags: jquery

I have a program which generates a div with a close button when a button is clicked. 
I somehow tackled, how to close the div when the click button is clicked, but the problem is when the i generate more than one div's at a time and click any of there close buttons it removes all the divs.

I've also managed [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/incrediblex/275efy85/14/) for demonstration.

**Note:** I haven't added button to generate the code for div, instead i have created 3 dummy divs in my JSFiddle just to demonstrate what i want.

HTML:

```
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/>   <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/>   <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/>   <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/>   <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/>   <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/>   <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageholder {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin:7px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #999;
    border:1px solid #999;
    position:relative;
}
.imageholder figcaption {
    font-style:italic;
    width:120px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.imageholder figcaption span {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#777;
}
.imageholder img {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
.imageholder .close {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: .99;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
closeBtn = $('.close');
imageHolder = $('.imageholder');
closeOnClick();

function closeOnClick() {
    closeBtn.on('click', function () {
        $(imageHolder).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Comment: Preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry i as unable to give url to my JSFIDDLE due to some error.

Comment: You can use `$(this).closest('.imageholder').remove();` inside click handler: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/275efy85/15/).

Comment: Did you read what the error said?

Comment: yes but i didn't got how to use JSFiddle link in my question.

Comment: @Fiddle thanku so much it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/275efy85/18/):

```
function closeOnClick() {
    closeBtn.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();// Close the div that contains the button clicked.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the parent div you want by calling .parent(imageHolder).remove().

```js
closeBtn = $('.close');
imageHolder = $('.imageholder');
closeOnClick();

function closeOnClick() {
    closeBtn.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('.imageholder').remove();
    });
}
```

```css
.imageholder {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin:7px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #999;
    border:1px solid #999;
    position:relative;
}
.imageholder figcaption {
    font-style:italic;
    width:120px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.imageholder figcaption span {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#777;
}
.imageholder img {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
.imageholder .close {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: .99;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/> <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/> <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/> <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/> <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="imageholder"> <span class='close'>x</span>

    <figure>
        <img src="${filePath}" alt="${fileName}" />
        <figcaption>${fileName}
            <br/> <span>Original Size: ${fileOriSize} KB</span>
            <br/> <span>Upload Size: ${fileUploadSize} KB</span>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the parent element with `$(this)`, then you get the desired effect. So the code is slightly changed to:

```
function closeOnClick() {
    closeBtn.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/275efy85/19/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(function() {
  $(".close").on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest(".imageholder").remove(); // or .hide()
  });
});
```